# Erro de sintaxe ReactApp

Tags: javascript, react, html

Boa noite, preciso fazer um site para a matéria de web, mas me deparei com o seguinte erro de sintaxe, o qual eu não faço ideia do que é, sou iniciante ainda.

**Componente principal**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Topo from './components/Topo';
  import './App.css';
  import './style.css'
  
 function App(){
   
    //constructor(props){
      //super(props);
    //  this.state = {nome:'AAA'};
   // }
  // O Erro acontece aqui em render
    render() {

      return(   
      <div className='App'>
        <Topo />
      </div>
      );
    }  

}
  

export default App;
```

**Componente que importei**

```
import React from 'react';



export default class Topo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='topo'>
                <header className = "header">
                    <div className="topo" role="menu">
                        <img src='img/asf_feather.png'/>
                            <p>
                                /Apache Cassandra
                                    </p>

                            <div className='dropdown'>
                                <img src='img/asf_feather.png'/>
                                    <button class="dropbtn">
                                        Apache Software Foundation

                                        </button>
                                    <div className="dropdown-content">

                                        <a href='#'>Apache Homepage</a>
                                        <a href='#'>License</a>
                                        <a href='#'>Sponsorship</a>
                                        <a href='#'>Thanks</a>
                                        <a href='#'>Sercurity</a>
                                    </div>
                                <div/>
                            </div>
                            <div className='imgtopo'/>
                                <img src='img/cassandra_logo.png'/>
                            </div>
                                <nav>
                                    <div className='botaomediaquery' onclick='teste()'>
                                        <button type="button" form="teste1" onclick="alert('Sem Funcionalidade')">
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul className='links'>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Home </a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Download  </a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Documentation </a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Comunity </a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Blog</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class='texto1'>
                                        <p>
                                            Manage massive amounts of data, fast, without losing sleep
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='botao'>
                                        <button type='button' form='teste1' onclick='alert("Sem Funcionalidade")'>
                                            Download Cassandra
                                            </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='CassadraDown'>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href='#'>Cassandra 4.0-beta1 Changelog</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                            </header>
                        </div>
                        
                    );
                
            }       

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tbm sou iniciante em React, mas quando vc cria um componente em React que é uma função, vc não tem o método "render", para retornar JSX você deve fazer assim:

```js
function App(){
    return(
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    )
}
```

Obs: A sintaxe de render é utilizada somente em componentes criados a partir de uma classe.

Comment: entendi, vou tentar aqui obrigado

Comment: Obrigado mesmo , funcionou.